# sort an array with item closest to two in middle and other extremes on other side - js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 3 numbers in an array that I want to order so that the item closest to 2 is in the middle, the lowest from two on the left and the highest from two on the right.

example 1 - `[2.3, 5.2, 1.2];` should change to `[1.2, 2.3, 5.2];`

example 2 -  `[1.1, 2.3, 0.3];` which should change to `[0.3, 2.3, 1.1];`

example 3 - `[1.3, 0.3, 2];` which should change to `[0.3, 2, 1.3];`

example 4 - `[2.2, 2.3, 2.1];` which should change to `[2.2, 2.1, 2.3];`

Currently I have the following but this is not ordering correctly. This puts the item closest to 2 at the front.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return Math.abs(1 - (a - 2)) - Math.abs(1 - (b - 2));
});
```

Can anyone see how this needs to be changed?

Comment: Your description makes it sound like you simply want them in order from lowest to highest. If I'm misreading, provide an example where they would not sort that way.

Comment: updated questions with more examples

Comment: If you have 3 numbers why bother use `sort`?

Comment: Your math: `Math.abs(1 - (a - 1)) - Math.abs(1 - (b - 1))` is equivalent to
`Math.abs(a) - Math.abs(b)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko i thought this was  the best way to approach the issue. If there is a better way I would love to hear it

Comment: If you want simple ascending order, just `return a-b` -- that might even be the default behavior of .sort

Comment: [0.3, 2, 1.3] after which logic??

Comment: @Faust its not exactly descending order. It's the number closest to `0` in the middle

Comment: @Jonasw after the sorting. I have included the sort function at the bottom of the question

Comment: What??  [2.1, 2.2, 2.3] ?? Isnt that [2.2,2.1,2.3]

Comment: @Jonasw apologies, small typo, updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a three step approach, first sort to get the closest to the given value, shift that value and sort the rest ascending. Then plice the temporary value to index `1`.

```js
function sort(array) {
    var temp = array.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(x - a) - Math.abs(x - b)).shift();
    array.sort((a, b) => a - b).splice(1, 0, temp);
    return array;
}

var x = 2;
console.log(sort([0, 1, 2]));
console.log(sort([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(sort([2, 3, 4]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another solution would be to collect the values with bigger delta in a new array and sort it. Later put the reduced value back to index `1`.

Advantage: No superfluous sort, while only one iteration is needed.

```js
function sort(array) {
    var temp = [],
        value = array.reduce((a, b) =>
            Math.abs(x - a) < Math.abs(x - b) ? (temp.push(b), a) : (temp.push(a), b)
        );

    temp.sort((a, b) => a - b).splice(1, 0, value);
    return temp;
}

var x = 2;
console.log(sort([0, 1, 2]));
console.log(sort([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(sort([2, 3, 4]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To easy, sort after distance to 2, then put the first into the second position:

```
arr.sort((a,b)=>Math.abs(a-2)-Math.abs(b-2));

arr=[arr[1],arr[0],arr[2]];
```

http://jsbin.com/kifitosopo/edit?console

Comment: no, that is not enought, because you use same absolute delta, which is in the end not the right sort order.

Comment: @nina scholz im not quite shure if the OP really checked his testcases... However, youre probably right +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using one reducer with straight forward rules.

```js
const diff = value => Math.abs(value - 2)

const sort = arr => arr.reduce(([min, closest, max], value) => {
    if(closest !== closest || diff(value) < diff(closest)) [closest, value] = [value, closest]

    if(min !== min || value < min ) min = value
    
    if(max !== max || value > max ) max = value
    
    return [min, closest, max]
    
  }, new Array(3).fill(NaN))


const tests = [
  [2.3, 5.2, 1.2],
  [1.1, 2.3, 0.3],
  [1.3, 0.3, 2],
  [2.2, 2.3, 2.1] 
]

tests.forEach(test => console.log(`[${test.join(', ')}] --> [${sort(test).join(', ')}]`))
```