# Javascript sort function to place element in the middle of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, sorting

Quite a few months ago, I tried to find a way to place an element in the middle of an array of 3 items using the javascript sort function. It looked like there was no clever way of achieving that result.

However, I recently found a working solution to this problem.
I then tried to generalize this solution to a bigger array of (5, 7, 9, ...) items. But, it seems to break when the size of the array exceeds 10 items.

Since I found the solution through trial and error rather than pure thinking, I hope someone is able to explain to me why everything seems to work fine until this seemingly arbitrary number.

Here is Codepen demo I created to illustrate the issue : https://codepen.io/TMLN/pen/PBoKgR?editors=0011

You can edit the line `ReactDOM.render(<Example items={example1} />...` and replace the prop `example1` by `example2`, `example3`, ... You'll see that everything starts breaking from `example5` but I really can't figure out why...

PS : this works on Chrome but for those using Edge, you might encounter a bug due to the way the browser handles the sort function.

Comment: `but for those using Edge`. Which nobody does on SO :D

Comment: please add some arrays and the wanted outcome as well. please add the code, you tried to the question, too.

Comment: Why use `sort` for this?  If you just need to arbitrarily place an item in the middle of an array, that's what `splice` is for.

Comment: is it something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325624/sort-an-array-with-item-closest-to-two-in-middle-and-other-extremes-on-other-sid), you want?

Comment: Using `sort` with a call to `indexOf` in its compare-callback is like giving your algorithm a *O(n²logn)* time complexity, while you can put an element in the middle of an array in *O(n)*. So yes, why do you insist on a really bad performing algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort callback function returns 0 when neither of the compared values is equal to the value to be moved. You probably intended to indicate with this zero that the relative position of *a* and *b* (the two compared values) should not change, but actually the zero means that the sort implementation should consider the two values *equal*, and so it is actually free to swap their positions. Only when the implementation is (what is called) *stable* can you be sure that the relative position of the two values will not change.

Others have found that in Chrome the `sort` function is *not* stable, which explains the erratic behaviour you notice. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/array-sort-sorting-stability-in-different-browsers) for the situation, with regard to a stable implementation, in different browsers.

To make it work on all JavaScript engines you should change your code, and return a non-zero value for *all* pairs you compare, based on the index they currently occupy.

Final note: using `sort` for this task is a bad choice: a good sorting algorithm has *O(nlogn)* time complexity, but if you need to find indexes of values inside the sort callback you actually add a factor *n* to that, making it *O(n²logn)*. To get an element out of an array and injecting it elsewhere is an operation that can be done in *O(n)* time. You can use `Array#splice` (twice) to do just that.

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks a lot ! In my previous implementation, I actually used splice to achieve the desired result but mainly because of convenience rather than execution speed. However, thanks to your informations and my curiosity being satisfied I can now choose wisely :)